# Как убрать эту ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Bот часть с терминала, это бот на питоне:

```
File "/Users/admin/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
"
```

Comment: Нужно переехать в страну, где РКН не блокирует доступ к серверам Телеграм. Или использовать VPN.

Answer (score 1):

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://LOGIN:PASSWORD@IP:1080'}
```

[pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy)